# How to download the sourcecode for Neatbeans 6.9 IDE

Tags: java, ide

I want to download the source code of NeatBeans IDE 6.9. Is its possible to so and if it is how to do that. I tried to search but could not find the exact point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Latest trunks](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/zip/) in zip, or [get from Mercurial](http://netbeans.org/community/sources/hg.html):

`$ hg clone http://hg.netbeans.org/main`

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for how to get the NetBeans sources are on the NetBeans website: http://NetBeans.org/community/sources/

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.netbeans.org/WorkingWithNetBeansSources